# Button to download images from galleria component of primefaces

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jsf-2.2, galleria

i'm using jsf 2.2 primefaces 6.0 and i already implemented a solution to display a list of images through "galleria" component of primefaces. The issue is now i'm trying to find solution in order to "download" all the images or each image from the galleria component through a button linked to the interface.

Here the xhtml code of the application:

```
<p:dialog header="Documents numérisés" widgetVar="diag" modal="true"
            dynamic="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="true"
            position="center" id="diagImages">
            <p:outputPanel id="gal" style="text-align:center;">
                <p:galleria value="#{demandeBean.demandeSelectionnee.images}"
                    panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313" showCaption="false"
                    autoPlay="false" var="image">
                    <p:graphicImage
                        value="http://localhost:18080/openCars/images/#{image}"
                        width="500" height="313" />
                </p:galleria>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:dialog>
```

Comment: please add you download image methode it will help us  to understand

Comment: i don't have a download method i think that one will propose me a javascript code in order to satisfy the need.

Comment: like upload a file in a download file you need to set a method

Comment: ok i will make a try to setup a method and if something wrong i will post it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching for a JS solution, this function can be useful:

```
$('.ui-galleria-panel img').each(function() {
   $(this).wrap("<a href='" + $(this).attr('src') + "' download='nameOfImage.jpg'></a>")
});
```

Basically this will wrap all the `<img>` with an `<a>` alongside the [download HTML5 attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).
The download will take place on image click.

If you need a button for each image, you can have a look at the following:

```
$('.ui-galleria-panel img').each(function() {
   $(this).after( "<a href='"+ $(this).attr('src') +"' download='nameOfImage.jpg' class='ui-button' style='position: absolute;right: 0;top: 0; padding: 5px 10px;background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);'><i class='fa fa-download'></i></a>" )
});
```

The result will be something like this.

[image: Galleria]

For the simplification of the example, I have included some embedded styles in the link, you may extract those into your css file and refer to it by adding the class alongside the ui-button one.

You may execute that once, preferably on dialog update oncomplete, or on dialog show.

Comment: i'm a beginner programmer pls can you made effort for me and add the download button because i can't deal with js i know only jsf and little bit of java

Comment: You need a button/link for each image ?

Comment: you can made a button for each image or for all images as you like both of the solutions satisfy my needs.

Comment: Alright, I have updated the answer based on your comment.

Comment: sorry for bothering you but where should i paste the code inside the galleria for exp ???

Comment: This is a JS code, you need to create a .js file and create a function and place that piece of code inside it, and make the call on document.ready of the gallaeria if it's being rendered right away on page load. I would suggest that you make some research on how to call a JS function in JSF env. Hope that helps.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function download() {
 $('.ui-galleria-panel img').each(function() {
     $(this).after( "<a href='"+ $(this).attr('src') +"' download='nameOfImage.jpg' class='ui-button' style='position: absolute;right: 0;top: 0; padding: 5px 10px;background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);'><i class='fa fa fa-download'></i></a>" )
  });
}
</script>  An error message appeared on 'src'

Comment: Yes something like this, and I have updated the answer to remove the extra "fa" from "fa fa fa-download"

Comment: there is problem with src i don't understand it and how to solve it

Comment: Open your chrome console or you firebug in firefox, and see if there's any error.

Comment: The download buttons does'nt appear on galleria component when i displayed images